# Undo Comment Voting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting

When I upvote (or downvote) a question or answer, I have a certain window of time to undo my vote. It doesn't seem this exists for upvotes on comments. (I haven't tried regarding comment flags because I couldn't try on random comments!) Why is this? Shouldn't we allow for mistaken clicks for comments too?

Comment: Tagging `status-declined` in light of the SE employee answer here and similar statements elsewhere (MSO IIRC).

Comment: @msh210 Time to update...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/166155):

Comment upvotes are now permanently removable within the first minute.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are a lower priority than posts, and upvoting a comment does not generate rep for the user.  A comment with an extra vote on it doesn't really matter, and it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Just curious: does the same apply to comment flagging?

Comment: There's no undo for flagging, post or comment.

Comment: Thanks!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​